# How to correctly implement memoization?

Tags: python, algorithm, memoization

I have been spending way too much time on a programming challenge:

Given a budget and a set of prices, compute all unique combinations on how to spend the entire budget.

### Example

#### Input

```
budget = 100
prices = [25, 50]
```

#### Output

```
[[25, 25, 25, 25], [25, 25, 50], [25, 50, 25], [50, 25, 25], [50, 50]]
```

I have implemented a brute force solution in Python that works correctly:

```py
def spend_the_budget(budget: int, prices: list) -> list:
    if budget == 0:
        return [[]]
    if budget < 0:
        return None

    combinations = []
    for price in prices:
        remainder = budget - price
        remainder_combinations = spend_the_budget(remainder, prices)
        if remainder_combinations is not None:
            for remainder_combination in remainder_combinations:
                remainder_combination += [price]
                combinations.append(remainder_combination)
    return combinations
```

However, this has obviously exponential time complexity and therefore doesn't scale in an acceptable fashion. Therefore I'd like to add memoization but can't seem to get it to work:

```py
def spend_the_budget_memoized(budget: int, prices: list, memo: dict = {}) -> list:
    if budget in memo:
        return memo[budget]
    if budget == 0:
        return [[]]
    if budget < 0:
        return None

    combinations = []
    for price in prices:
        remainder = budget - price
        remainder_combinations = spend_the_budget_memoized(remainder, prices, memo)
        if remainder_combinations is not None:
            for remainder_combination in remainder_combinations:
                remainder_combination += [price]
                combinations.append(remainder_combination)
    memo[budget] = combinations
    return combinations
```

Weirdly enough however, this yields an incorrect result and I just can't wrap around my head as to what I did wrong here:

#### Output

```
[[25, 25, 25, 50, 25, 25, 50], [50, 25, 25, 50], [25, 25, 25, 50, 25, 25, 50], [25, 25, 25, 50, 25, 25, 50], [50, 25, 25, 50]]
```

Comment: You are appending (via +=) to memoized values. That's going to update previously computed results.

Answer (score 0):

```
for remainder_combination in remainder_combinations:
                remainder_combination += [price]
                combinations.append(remainder_combination)
```

When you iterate over `remainder_combinations` you are iterating over the same copy which is stored in `memo`. Use list.copy() instead,

```
for remainder_combination in remainder_combinations:
                temp = remainder_combination.copy()
                temp += [price]
                combinations.append(temp)
```